# Create separate JavaScript bundles with a shared common library using Browserify and Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify

For my team at work, I'm trying to set up a semi-**automated** JavaScript script and dependency management system with the help of Gulp and Browserify.

I'm not even sure if what I'm trying to achieve is possible with the currently available set of tools (and my limited JavaScript knowledge). I believe what I'm trying to achieve is a pretty common scenario, but I haven't been able to find the information I've been looking for.

Consider the following diagram:

[image]

The lines indicate depedencies. For shared modules, such as *Module-v* and *Module-y*, I don't want the scripts to be duplicated by being included in each of their respective bundles.

I know that using Browserify I can manually ignore or exclude modules, which is fine when the project is young - but as the project grows managing which dependencies need to be included where is going to become very cumbersome.

A [similar Q&A here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874894/how-to-use-gulp-to-build-javascript-bundles) I think has the same essence of what I'm trying to ask, but to me, it isn't quite clear. It also references [gulp-browserify which has since been blacklisted](https://github.com/resource/fabricator/issues/35).

In my diagram, I can see that I have three Browserify *entry points*, but my lack of Gulp/Node/Browserify experience means I'm struggling to wrap my head around how I can try to achieve what I want to.

I'm happy to do the work to try and piece it together, as I already have been trying - however project managers are breathing down my neck so I'm having to hack together a temporary "solution" until I can implement something a little more automated and robust.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

It seems from [Browserify's plugin documentation](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#plugins) that this might be able to be achieved by using [factor-bundle](https://github.com/substack/factor-bundle) which [substack](https://github.com/substack) [pointed out to me](https://twitter.com/substack/status/468238717753524224); however again due to my lack of Node/Browserify/Gulp experience I am struggling to pull all the pieces together.

**Related Questions**

- [How can I use factor-bundle with browserify programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22224951/how-can-i-use-factor-bundle-with-browserify-programmatically)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

*Figured it out, sharing the learns:*

Code example:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    source = require('vinyl-source-stream'),
    browserify = require('browserify'),
    factor = require('factor-bundle');

gulp.task('browserify', function(){

    return browserify({
        entries: ['blog.js', 'page.js']
    })
    .plugin(factor, {
        // File output order must match entry order
        o: ['bundle/blog.js', 'bundle/page.js']
    })
    .bundle({
        debug: true
    })
    .pipe(source('common.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('bundle/'));

});
```

The key difference between this output and the diagram, is that the `common.js` file is automatically generated based on common depenedencies between `blog.js` and `page.js`. This is described in the [factor-bundle documentation](https://github.com/substack/factor-bundle#example).

**Notes:**

- I found that Node would throw an error if the output files didn't already exist. I'm unsure why as I would have assumed that factor-bundle would simply write a stream to the outputting file regardless of whether it was there or not. As a workaround, after 'cleaning' the output directory, I simply created 'placeholder' files to keep it happy.
- I haven't figured out how to access the [factor-bundle stream event](https://github.com/substack/factor-bundle#fronstream-function-stream-) when using it as a browserify plugin (it may not even be possible), so any further work on the output files (such as uglifying etc) would likely need to be done somewhere else in the pipeline, possibly with another browserify plugin, or even after the fact.

Comment: NOTE: Please be aware that currently there is a bug with using factor-bundle as a Browserify plugin where dependencies can get "mixed" up. See this issue for details: https://github.com/substack/factor-bundle/issues/13

Comment: looks like that bug has been fixed, but thanks for the link.

Comment: @justrhysism. Hi. I am trying to do something similar. I was able to split the code into multiple bundles but unable to figure out a proper way to dynamically require the bundles. Have you tried loading the bundles dynamically?

Comment: @Dhawal Sorry for the delayed response. No I haven't been able to load the bundles dynamically, however this is deliberate as I want to be explicit about which bundles I'm including and where.

Comment: I have actually found a better way to do this recently, when I get some time I'll update the answer.

Comment: Please do, I am also trying to do this

Comment: @justrhysism so, when do u have some time? ;)

Comment: @Brettetete Sorry, this is still on my radar. Plate is really full at the moment.

Comment: @justrhysism: Please, I'd be very interested in case you'd want to share your solution.

Comment: Reminds me of Fermat's last theorum: "I have an elegant solution to this which unfortunately is too large for this margin ..." then leaves one of the biggest mathematical puzzles for centuries

Comment: (still waiting :P)

Comment: @sodimel yeah I'm not going to lie, I've long forgotten what the better way was for Browserify + Gulp.

Browserify was a fantastic step on the path to better things—but these days I can't see the utility of it when there's so many better (and more mature, better documented) tools available now. The landscape has changed vastly since 2014.