# Gulp + Browserify bundling dependency

Tags: gulp, bundle, browserify

on `libs/index.jsx`
all library were called using require
ex. `require('jquery')...`

and it generates a bundle with jquery in it

on `app/index.jsx`
I called the same thing on app.js but the whole jquery codes are still adding
to the bundle on the app.js

Can anyone help me how can I depend my `app.js` to the `libs.js` on the output files? Here's my code:

```
    'use strict';

    var gulp = require('gulp');
    var notify = require('gulp-notify');
    var rename = require('gulp-rename');
    var browserify = require('browserify');
    var babelify = require('babelify');
    var watchify = require('watchify');
    var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
    var es = require('event-stream');

    gulp.task('default', function() {

        // we define our input files, which we want to have bundled:
        var files = [
          'build/js/app/index.jsx',
          'build/js/libs/index.jsx'
        ];
        var outputFiles = [
          'app.js',
          'libs.js'
        ];

        // map them to our stream function
        var tasks = files.map(function(entry, index) {

          // browserify instance
          var bundler = browserify({
            entries: [entry]
          });

          // Watchify to watch source file changes
          bundler.plugin(watchify, {
            // ignore this folders
            ignoreWatch: [
              '**/node_modules/**',
              '**/bower_components/**'
            ]
          });

          // Babel tranforms, transform .jsx files to native js
          bundler.transform(babelify, {
            presets: ['es2015', 'react']
          });

          // bundle the files
          bundler.bundle()
                 .pipe(source(outputFiles[index]))
                 // rename them to have "bundle as postfix"
                 .pipe(rename({
                     extname: '.bundle.js'
                 }))
                 .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'))
                 .pipe(notify({
                   message: 'Generated file: ',
                 }));

          return bundler;
        });
    });
```

the output files created in dist/js folder were `libs.bundle.js` and `app.bundle.js`. I want two separate files with one dependent to the other, which is the app.bundle.js. Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [factor-bundle](https://github.com/substack/factor-bundle). Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23795802)

Comment: nice! It resolves my issue. "factor-bundle" is the right one I was looking for.